# How to handle MariaDB System-Versioned Tables with Doctrine ORM?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb, doctrine-migrations

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
       id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
       name VARCHAR(255),
       amount INT
) WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING;
```

> The WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING clause initializes hidden, system-managed
> `row_start` and `row_end` columns for tracking changes by row.

The corresponding entity does not have these fields (`row_start`, `row_end`) which are managed by MariaDB.

When I try to run any doctrine command, for example `symfony console doctrine:schema:update`, I get the following error:

```
In SchemaException.php line 85:
                                                                    
  There is no column with name 'row_end' on table 'accounts'.
```

[MariaDB System-Versioned Tables](https://mariadb.com/docs/appdev/temporal-tables/)

Comment: these vendor specific stuff is always a problem. system versioning apparently only exists in the enterprise version since 10.3 (current is 10.5)... I've found this issue: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3273 which doesn't seem to have had any lasting consequences or support. apparently someone wanted to extend the 10.2 abstraction layer ... and was never heard of again? especially, hidden columns are really really weird. the issue describes the problem.

Comment: Yes, what a problem. I think I have to do without Doctrine commands, or implement my own versioning system. Thank you anyway.